# How do i list the file content's selected lines?

Tags: shell, unix

I want to list the content of the file from fourth to the last line and then display the content form first to third line and append both o/p in a new file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will print from 4th to last line.

```
awk 'NR>=4' file
```

This will print from first to 3rd line.

```
awk 'NR<4' file
```

To have all the output in this order:

```
awk 'NR>=4' file >  new_file
awk 'NR<4'  file >> new_file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
$ awk 'NR>=4' a
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
$ awk 'NR<4' a
line1
line2
line3
$ awk 'NR>=4' a > new_file
$ awk 'NR<4' a >> new_file
$ cat new_file 
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line1
line2
line3
```

#### Update

You can also do it using `head` and `tail`:

```
$ tail -n +4 a
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
$ head -n 3 a
line1
line2
line3
```

We use the `-n` option of `tail` with `+`:

> -n, --lines=K
>
> output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; **or use -n +K to
>   output lines starting with the Kth**

Comment: I didn't know it would be this simple, i was using head and tail  and couldn't figure it out. Thank you very much

Comment: So..you couldn't make head or tail of it?! Haha.  Useful answer, thanks fedorqui.

Comment: @Suraj I updated my answer with a `head` && `tail` version. It was a little tricky.

Comment: A better solution than `awk 'NR<4' file` would be `awk 'NR==4{nextfile}1' file`, so that you don't run through an entire long file comparing each line number to see if it's less than 4.

Comment: That's interesting, @ghoti. However I try `awk 'NR==4{nextfile}1' myfile` and does print everything.

Comment: Yes, I updated my comment later on :) Anyway, now it is printing all the lines. This did work: `awk 'NR==4{exit}1' file`

Comment: `awk 'NR==4{nextfile}1' a` prints all the lines (10 in my case, it is the file of my answer)

Comment: In general, I would expect `nextfile` and `exit` to be equivalent.  For me, it only prints lines 1 to 3, both in BSDawk and Gawk.  What awk are you using?

Comment: I am using `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996`

Comment: Odd.  I see the same correct behaviour with the same version of mawk on an old Ubuntu box here.  I can't explain the behaviour you're seeing, unless perhaps the line endings in your input file are wonky.  What does `seq 1 10 | awk 'NR==4{nextfile}1'` do?

Comment: I haven't seen this behaviour before.  Of course, I don't use mawk much.  It's entirely possible that `nextfile` is implemented differently in different versions of awk.  Good to know that this is inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks very much for showing me the existence of `nextfile`, it was interesting discovering it and also its inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done using sed:

```
$ sed -ne '4,$p' inp.txt > out.txt
$ sed -ne '4q;p' inp.txt >> out.txt
```

The last line could be shortened to `sed 3q inp.txt >> out.txt` if you like.  I did it this way so that if you wanted to auto-generate your sed script using a single breakpoint, you wouldn't need to do any extra math.

Of course, you could also make this a more complex one-liner:

```
$ sed -ne '1x;2,3H;4,$p;${x;p;}' inp.txt > out.txt
```

The breakdown is this:

- `1x` - Store the first line in sed's "hold" buffer.
- `2,3H` - Append subsequent lines to the "hold" buffer, up to our breakpoint.
- `4,$p` - If the current line number is "4 to the end", just print it.
- `${x;p;}` - On the last line, swap the hold buffer and pattern space, then print.

This may look a bit arcane.  And it is.  And requires a bit more math if your breakpoint ("4") is a number that will change.  But sed is *tiny*, and this runs as a single process, so it will likely be quite a bit faster if you're processing many files this way.

Answer (score 0):

One more ways you can do try this:-

For Single line
This will print only 5 number of selected line in file

```
sed -n '5p' yourFilesPath
```

For Multiple lines

```
sed -n '1,5p' yourFilesPath
```

Comment: Also using this you can start printing the lines from any random numbers whichever you wanted to print

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using 'head' and 'tail' command is that you need to know the total number of lines in the given file. You can use 'wc' command to know the number of lines in the file.

`wc -l < file` will give you the number of lines.

`` echo `expr \`wc -l < file\` - 3` `` will give you the number of lines > 3. Feed it to tail command. That's it.

-bash-2.05b$ `` tail -`expr \`wc -l < file\` - 3` file ``
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
-bash-2.05b$
-bash-2.05b$ head -3 file
line1
line2
line3
-bash-2.05b$
-bash-2.05b$ `` tail -`expr \`wc -l < file\` - 3` file `` > output_file
-bash-2.05b$ head -3 file >> output_file
-bash-2.05b$
-bash-2.05b$ cat output_file
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line1
line2
line3

Not as elegant as the answers posted earlier but just another way of doing it. Please note that this solution will work till the number of lines are >= 3 :)